# Where does campaign source "LIN" come from in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, referrer, campaigns

We are running digital campaigns on two websites and both are recording a top traffic driver where the campaign source = LIN. There are no other campaign parameters (campaign, medium, etc.) and we cannot figure out where this traffic is coming from. It does not seem to be spam because there is engagement, goal completions, returning sessions, etc. The Full Referrer is also listed as LIN. It is being grouped under the (other) channel.

Is there any way we can determine where this traffic is coming from?